# Are unquoted special characters legal in an RFC 5322 email display name if they're in an encoded word?

Tags: email, smtp, rfc5322

Take the address

```
foo:bar <user@example.com>
```

As I understand it the colon in the display name `foo:bar`, being a special character, should be part of a quoted string, e.g. `"foo:bar" <user@example.com>`

In this next example the display name `foo:bar` is in an (RFC2047?)  encoded word, but the colon isn't quoted before encoding. Is this a legal address? I've run into a tool that won't accept it, but I'm unsure if it's a bug or strictly correct behaviour.

```
=?UTF-8?B?Zm9vOmJhcg==?= <user@example.com>
```

I guess the other way of putting question is, should the RFC5322 validation be done before or after the RFC2047 header decoding?

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 2047 6.2 says](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047#section-6.2):

> NOTE: Decoding and display of encoded-words occurs **after** a structured field body is parsed into tokens.  It is therefore possible to hide 'special' characters in encoded-words which, when displayed, will be indistinguishable from 'special' characters in the surrounding text.  For this and other reasons, it is NOT generally possible to translate a message header containing 'encoded-word's to an unencoded form which can be parsed by an RFC 822 mail reader.

`display-name` is a token, so my reading of the spec is that your last example is a valid address - the validation should be done on the encoded value, and then decoded for display later.

[Section 5 also says](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc2047#section-5):

> Use of 'encoded-word's to represent strings of purely ASCII characters is allowed, but discouraged.

So in this example you'd be encouraged to use the quoted form `"foo:bar" <user@example.com>`, and not use unnecessary encoded words.